# Get Ruby project root path from a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've started to build a Gem by my self.

Now from my Gem I need get the root path from the ruby project what are using it.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to access the root path of the project using your gem from within your gem? Is the project always going to be a Rails app?

Comment: If its a rails engine you can use `Rails.root`

Comment: Jeremywoertink. Yes, I need to access the root path of a rails project using my gem from within my gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this forum: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/143383
From my understanding of your question, you want to get the path of the project NOT the path of where the gem itself is located.

```
class MyGem

   def self.get_working_dir
     Dir.pwd
   end

end

> MyGem.get_working_dir
> /Users/your_name/my_project_directory
```

This solution ended up helping out a Gem I had made where I had to iterate through a project's file tree.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can using the gem list command

Here an example.

```
$ gem list green_shoes -d

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

green_shoes (1.1.374)
    Author: ashbb
    Homepage: http://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes
    Installed at: d:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0

    Green Shoes
```

From withing a Ruby gem this can be done like this

```
spec = Gem::Specification.find_by_name("green_shoes")
puts spec.gem_dir

# d:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/green_shoes-1.1.374
```

Comment: Thank you peter but I need to access the root path of a rails project using my gem from within my gem.